# Structure of the unit group $(\mathbb{Z}[i]/8\mathbb{Z}[i])^\times$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, ring-theory, finite-groups, abelian-groups

I know that $\mathbb{Z}[i]/8\mathbb{Z}[i]=\{a+ib \mid a,b\in\mathbb{Z}_8\}$.

But I'm not able to comprehend what $(\mathbb{Z}[i]/8\mathbb{Z}[i])^\times$ is.

Can someone please help me get its elements and generators?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Because $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ is a PID, we have Bezout's identity ([Wikipedia link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout's_identity)), so we can see that $a+bi\in\mathbb{Z}[i]$ becomes a unit when considered in $\mathbb{Z}[i]/(8)$ iff $\gcd(a+bi,8)=1$. The factorization of $8$ in $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ is $$8=2^3=i(1+i)^6$$
so $a+bi$ becomes a unit modulo $8$ iff $\gcd(a+bi,1+i)=1$.

Now plot elements of $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ representing the $64$ congruence classes in $\mathbb{Z}[i]/(8)$ – a good choice would be the elements $\{a+bi:0\leq a,b\leq 7\}$ – cross out the multiples of $1+i$ in that range, and whatever's left represent the congruence classes in $\mathbb{Z}[i]/(8)$ that are units.